# Google Analytics analytics.js Anonymous Score Reporting

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics.js

So I'm trying to set up Google Analytics for my web game. I need to send over a score and I've gotten that working, but the problem is when I test the game and check my custom report the next day then I see only one entry and it seems like it just added up all the scores and put them into one entry. I believe the solution is to use dimensions to make multiple entries. Here's what I have right now for sending over data to analytics.

```
var rid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
});

// send over relevant analytics data to Google Analytics
ga('set', 'dimension1', rid);
ga('set', 'metric1', NJ.analytics.blocksCleared);
ga('send', 'event', 'Game', 'end', 'Game Session Data');
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct solution and it might also create duplicate data since I'm just generating a random string. Can someone confirm that this is how you generate rows of custom variables in analytics.js and suggest a better method of generating unique anonymous users for analytics.js?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but metrics being added up is expected behavior, and adding a dimension is indeed necessary if you want to get a "breakdown" of the collected values (you need to include the dimension in the report). As far as I understand your question you are approaching this correctly.

Comment: Right, but my concern is the way that I'm setting the dimension value is by a random ID so that they'll be mostly unique. Since there could still be conflicts I was wondering if there was a way to put unique values in dimension.

Comment: It seems you are generating a UUID ( I think i recognize the code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript). Unless you start with the slightly optimistic assumption that your application will survive the next three universes that should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Having a single row for each score is not very helpful by itself. If you still want to do it though, custom dimensions is the way to go. I am not sure if that is going to provide the data you need though.

The primary question is: What do you want to do with the data you are collecting? If you are interested in the average of scores, you can look at [event value](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) field.

Custom metrics by definition are aggregates and will result in a single value over a period.